# knockout observable array update not updating the UI

Tags: javascript, user-interface, knockout.js

When I update an `observable` element of Knockout the UI is not getting update
**HTML**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: students, visible: !students().isDeleted">
     <tr>
         <td data-bind="text: RollNo"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: Phone"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: Email"></td>
         <td>
             <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.editStudent">Edit</a>
             <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.deleteStudent">Delete</a>
         </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Javascript**

```
function StudentModel(student){
    this.RollNo = ko.observable(student.RollNo);
    this.Name = ko.observable(student.Name);
    this.Phone = ko.observable(student.Phone);
    this.Email = ko.observable(student.Email);
    this.isDeleted = ko.observable(student.isDeleted);
    this.isEdited = ko.observable(student.isEdited);
}

function StudentViewModel() {
    //Array of students
    this.students = ko.observableArray();

    //Data retrived from the server
    var listStudent= JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(ViewBag.StudentsList));;
    var mappedStudents = $.map(listStudent, function(student) { return new StudentModel(student) });

    //Map it to show the data
    this.students(mappedStudents);

    //Delete student
    this.deleteStudent= function(student){
        var stu = this.students()[this.students.indexOf(student)];
        stu.isDeleted(true);
    }.bind(this);
```

When I click on `Delete` the UI is not updated... When I try `stu.isDeleted=true;` still it does not works... Any help would be appreciated...

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fALs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the databinding.

```
visible: !students().isDeleted
```

This looks up the `isDeleted` property in the observable array. Which doesn't exist, so it is false and will always show all the elements.

If you want to hide the students the visible binding should be on the `<tr>`.

If you want to remove the student from the observable array you can just remove it.

http://jsfiddle.net/8fALs/2/

Comment: What was the precise mistake I was doing..?

Comment: The visible binding is bound to the tbody, not the items. Also the bindingcontext on the tbody is your viewmodel, and not a studentmodel. So when you access students() you access the observable array in your studentViewModel.